# Python watchdog for 2 different directory and to execute 2 different handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, watchdog, python-watchdog

I want to watch 2 different directory for receiving 2 different names of PDF files and on receive of any PDF file, I want to execute some Command prompt script in the Event_Handler. I can create 2 separate files for my problem, but I want to keep watching these files using single python code. could you please guide me how and where we can put If-Else condition or other approach to handle this problem in my below code.

with 2 separate code file, I am able to archive this.
I can understand this code will work only for one class because of **while loop - time.sleep(5). but not able to think alternative approach

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import subprocess

class Watcher1:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH1 = "C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\FinalOCR\\Diageo\\SampleInvoices"

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run1(self):
        event_handler1 = Handler1()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler1, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH1, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler1(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
               subprocess.call([
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\AppData\\Local\\UiPath\\app-19.7.0\\UiRobot.exe',
                '/file',
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\FinalOCR\\InvoiceAutomation\\PDFReadwithNative.xaml'
                ])    

class Watcher2:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH2 = "C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\SecondOCR\\Diageo\\SampleInvoices"

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run2(self):
        event_handler2 = Handler2()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler2, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH2, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler2(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
               subprocess.call([
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\AppData\\Local\\UiPath\\app-19.7.0\\UiRobot.exe',
                '/file',
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\SecondOCR\\InvoiceAutomation\\PDFReadwithNative.xaml'
```

Like this I am call the Main method:

```
 if __name__ == '__main__': 
       w1 = Watcher1() 
       w1.run1() 
       w2 = Watcher2() 
       w2.run2()
```

Comment: create only one `while True` in `"__main__"` OR you will have to run every watcher in separated thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move `while True` from class to `__main__`

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    w1 = Watcher1() 
    w2 = Watcher2() 

    w1.start() 
    w2.start() 

    try:
       while True:
           time.sleep(5)
    except:
        w1.stop() 
        w2.stop() 
        print("Error")

    w1.join() 
    w2.join()
```

And there is no need to use numbers `1` `2` in separated classes for `event_handler1`/`event_handler2` and `DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH1`/`DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH2`

---

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import subprocess

class Handler1(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
               subprocess.call([
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\AppData\\Local\\UiPath\\app-19.7.0\\UiRobot.exe',
                '/file',
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\FinalOCR\\InvoiceAutomation\\PDFReadwithNative.xaml'
                ])    

class Handler2(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
               subprocess.call([
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\AppData\\Local\\UiPath\\app-19.7.0\\UiRobot.exe',
                '/file',
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\SecondOCR\\InvoiceAutomation\\PDFReadwithNative.xaml'
                ])    


class Watcher1:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\FinalOCR\\Diageo\\SampleInvoices"

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def start(self):
        event_handler = Handler1()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()

    def stop(self)
        self.observer.stop()

    def join(self)
        self.observer.join()


class Watcher2:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\SecondOCR\\Diageo\\SampleInvoices"

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def start(self):
        event_handler = Handler2()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()

    def stop(self)
        self.observer.stop()

    def join(self)
        self.observer.join()


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    w1 = Watcher1() 
    w2 = Watcher2() 

    w1.start() 
    w2.start() 

    try:
       while True:
           time.sleep(5)
    except:
        w1.stop() 
        w2.stop() 
        print("Error")

    w1.join() 
    w2.join()
```

---

Because classes are very similar so it could be one class with different arguments

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import subprocess

class Handler1(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
               subprocess.call([
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\AppData\\Local\\UiPath\\app-19.7.0\\UiRobot.exe',
                '/file',
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\FinalOCR\\InvoiceAutomation\\PDFReadwithNative.xaml'
               ])    

class Handler2(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
               subprocess.call([
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\AppData\\Local\\UiPath\\app-19.7.0\\UiRobot.exe',
                '/file',
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\SecondOCR\\InvoiceAutomation\\PDFReadwithNative.xaml'
               ])


class Watcher:

    def __init__(self, directory, handler):
        self.directory = directory
        self.handler = handler
        self.observer = Observer()

    def start(self):
        self.observer.schedule(self.handler, self.directory, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()

    def stop(self)
        self.observer.stop()

    def join(self)
        self.observer.join()


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    w1 = Watcher("C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\FinalOCR\\Diageo\\SampleInvoices", Handler1()) 
    w2 = Watcher("C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\SecondOCR\\Diageo\\SampleInvoices", Handler2()) 

    w1.start() 
    w2.start() 

    try:
       while True:
           time.sleep(5)
    except:
        w1.stop() 
        w2.stop() 
        print("Error")

    w1.join() 
    w2.join()
```

---

Handlers are also very similar so probably you could reduce them to one handler with different arguments

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import subprocess

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self, path):
        super().__init__()
        self.path = path        

    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
               subprocess.call([
                'C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\AppData\\Local\\UiPath\\app-19.7.0\\UiRobot.exe',
                '/file',
                self.path
               ])    

class Watcher:

    def __init__(self, directory, handler):
        self.directory = directory
        self.handler = handler
        self.observer = Observer()

    def start(self):
        self.observer.schedule(self.handler, self.directory, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()

    def stop(self)
        self.observer.stop()

    def join(self)
        self.observer.join()


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    handler1 = Handler('C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\FinalOCR\\InvoiceAutomation\\PDFReadwithNative.xaml')
    handler2 = Handler('C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\SecondOCR\\InvoiceAutomation\\PDFReadwithNative.xaml')

    w1 = Watcher("C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\FinalOCR\\Diageo\\SampleInvoices", handler1) 
    w2 = Watcher("C:\\Users\\BPM_admin\\Desktop\\SecondOCR\\Diageo\\SampleInvoices", handler2) 

    w1.start() 
    w2.start() 

    try:
       while True:
           time.sleep(5)
    except:
        w1.stop() 
        w2.stop() 
        print("Error")

    w1.join() 
    w2.join()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for above explanation, with this my problem got solved and lot of my basic python concept got cleared, I am new python technology , so your input has helped me a lot, again thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to watch 2 different directories with python watchdog. Searched stackoverflow where this post seems to be the most recent. After trying out different solutions I use the below one due to its simplicity. Thought I'd post it for any other coming upon this thread that wants a simple solution.

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEvent


class MyEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, callback) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.callback = callback

    def on_modified(self, event: FileSystemEvent):
        #  TODO add your own logic here
        self.callback()

    #  TODO add more methods here if needed.
    #  See docs for which method names to use for event handling:
    #  https://python-watchdog.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #  You don't need to subclass Observer for simple use cases.
    observer = Observer()

    #  Just call observer.schedule for each separate directory you need to watch.
    #  One instance of Observer can watch several directories if you don't need more threads for performance.
    #  TODO replace callable1/callable2 with functions of your own.
    #  TODO replace "path/to/dir1" and "path/to/dir2" with paths to dirs to watch.
    observer.schedule(MyEventHandler(callable1), path="path/to/dir1", recursive=False)
    observer.schedule(MyEventHandler(callable2), path="path/to/dir2", recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(300)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nUser abort intercepted!")
    finally:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```